# Configuring phpmyadmin on nginx server for laravel project

Tags: nginx, phpmyadmin, laravel

I have been trying to install phpmyadmin on the nginx server for laravel project, i have installed the phpmyadmin and setup the symlink to point /var/www/laravel/phpmyadmin.

When i am trying to access the phpmyadmin using /phpmyadmin, I am getting the 404 error from laravel.

What should i do to avoid this error and get the phpmyadmin on my server.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used Heidi SQL instead of phpmyadmin, and it worked like a charm. I dont need to install phpmyadmin at at all.

I followed these steps mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15663001/remote-connections-mysql-ubuntu

Thanks @daniel for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

Do *not* use PhpMyAdmin!

There are other, secure and *nicer* alternatives, which include using MySQL SSH tunnel. Virtually any modern MySQL GUI client allows you to connect to the server using SSH connectivity.

If you can SSH to the server, you can setup MySQL GUI client connection.

Comment: I tried using HeidiSQL, when i enter my IP address and credentials, i can see the connection error.
Should I need to make some changes to server side?